# Show one div and hide another div using Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I would like to show and hide div using Angularjs, but i am new in Angular so need some help Thanks in Advance.

```
<a href="#">I want to fire event on click of this a tag</a>
<div  style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red;">I want to show this     element</div>
 <div  style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red;">I want to Hide this element</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

controller.js:

```
 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showDiv = '1';

    $scope.toggleShow = function(){
       $scope.showDiv = !$scope.showDiv;
    }
 });
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <a href="#" ng-click="toggleShow()">I want to fire event on click of this a tag</a>
    <div ng-show="showDiv" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red;">Show this element</div><br>
    <div ng-hide="showDiv" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: green;">Hide this element</div>
</body>
```

Here is the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/DWobFzvas9x4lhaoNfTI.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but just want to know that how to show on click of that a tag